# ListBox Windows phone

Tags: c#, asp.net, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to display a list of element in a Grid. it contains two columns and two rows. Help me, please.

```
Item1 in Grid.row=0 Grid.column=0,
Item2 in Grid.row=0 Grid.column=1...
```

xaml code:

```
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>


                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="AllDeal" >

                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="240"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="240"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="229"></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="229"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Border Background="#b09f4e"></Border>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" FontSize="48"  Margin="0,10,97,164" RenderTransformOrigin="0.546,0.074"  >75%</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White"  Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,69,22,114"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding numberday}" Foreground="Blue" Margin="168,176,0,0" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="DAYS" Foreground="Blue" Margin="168,198,0,218" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="#b8a54b"></Border>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Margin="0,69,22,114"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="48"  Margin="0,10,97,164" RenderTransformOrigin="0.546,0.074"  >15%</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding numberday}" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="Blue" Margin="168,176,0,0" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="DAYS" Foreground="Blue" Grid.Column="1" Margin="168,198,0,218" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>


                        <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="#bfb274"></Border>



                        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="#c7bc85"></Border>

                        <ListBoxItem>

                        </ListBoxItem>


        </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>



        </ListBox>
```

Comment: why do you need the list? just create a grid 2x2, and add what you want in each row/column

Comment: in my C # code I sent a list of element

Comment: I found the solution. I just need to add in my xaml code  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <toolkit:WrapPanel  ItemWidth="230" ItemHeight="250"   Width="600"/>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>